# I can't run magento2 sample data after magento installation. Authentication required

Tags: magento2, command-line

I am trying to run sample data using command line. I used the following command

```
composer config repositories.magento composer http://packages.magento.com
composer require magento/sample-data:1.0.0-beta
```

But after running the script it stops at `Authentication
username:
password`

And the `password`don't show anything even when typing on it. Afterwards i get `Authentication failed` returning composer.json to previous.

Is there a way to run without authentication? or is there something am doing wrong?

Comment: `password` isn't supposed to show anything, it's a security feature. If you enter your authentication keys when prompted, it should succeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get your credentials by logging in to [Magento Marketplace](https://marketplace.magento.com/) with a user name and password, then going to My Account > Connect > Developers > Secure Keys.

For more details, check this:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/connect-auth.html

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: i did but it's access keys i saw and used but getting failure

Comment: You have to use the same keys you used when you originally installed Magento.